# Search Array and Set Environment Variables

Tags: postman

My Postman response body is this:

```
{
"jobs": [
    {
        "id": "00d21be0",
        "name": "IT Department"
    },
    {
        "id": "h27da349",
        "name": "Car Sales"
    },
    {
        "id": "5d2db4125",
        "name": "Grocery Clerk"
    },
    {
        "id": "65cd0cc1d",
        "name": "Accounting Department"
    },
    {
        "id": "8462284587",
        "name": "Nurse"
    },
    {
        "id": "9fe2ff9ee4",
        "name": "Astronaut"
    },
    {
        "id": "f40cb44799",
        "name": "Phone Operator"
    },
    {
        "id": "f4e0483257",
        "name": "Project Leader"
    }
]
```

}

What I would like to do is parse this response and set an Environmental Variable for id's associated with Nurse, Astronaut, and Grocery Clerk.  The rest of the info I do not need.  I cannot use the array [number] because its not a guarantee they come in the same order on other systems.

Is JSON.stringify response body the way to go? How do I pull those values?

My Postman test so far is:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentalVariable("jobs", JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is parse your json body with a loop and, when you hit the names you want, you set a global variable with the corresponding id, like :

```
// get the response body
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
// init counter
var loop_count = 0

for (count = 0; count < jsonData.jobs.length; count++)
{
    if (jsonData.jobs[count].name == "Nurse")
    {
        var job_id = jsonData.jobs[count].id;
        postman.setEnvironmentalVariable("env_nurse", job_id);
    }
}
```

This is the principle.

You can do if/else for the different names you want to catch but I don't recommend it (use an array that you can expand easily).

Same thing for the environment variable name, instead of hard coding, try to generate it with respect to your element name.

Comment: Thank You.  This is working.  I do have a question another question.  Why is var loop_count indented?